# Объединение ячеек одного столбца по общим данным второго столбца

Tags: excel

Kак можно реализовать данную задачу, если в  первом столбце содержатся две пачки данных, которые нужно объединить по общим данным второго столбца.

Т.е. в этом случае необходимо как-то прописать условие, но как - вопрос?

Данных может быть огромное количество, поэтому действий с копированием/переносом данных не получится.

Буду благодарен, если поможете, а то весь день голову ломаю.

Comment: У меня есть догадки использовать ВПР, но верны ли они...

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Объединение ячеек и объединение данных - разные действия.